# Can't access specific object value of array of objects in Vue 3 deep watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I can't access the value of a specific object prop in an array through a deep watcher in Vue3.

I don't know if there's a problem with proxy arrays that are holding proxy objects.

I have the following data structure from a pinia store:

```
rule: [
  {
    key: "root",
    data: "root1 data",
    label: "",
    selectListItems: [
      {
        label: "root1",
        data: "root1",
      },{
        data: "root2",
        label: "root2",
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
     key: "leaf1",
     data: "leaf1 data",
     label: "",
     selectListItems: [
       {
         data: "leaf1_1",
         label: "leaf1_1",
       },{
         data: "leaf1_2",
         label: "leaf1_2",
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

and later in my `Component.vue` I filled a list like this and defined a watcher

```
<script setup>
const root = store.getRule..find((e) => e.hasOwnProperty('key') && e.key === 'root')
const leaf1= store.getRule..find((e) => e.hasOwnProperty('key') && e.key === 'leaf1')
const listCollection = ref([])

listCollection.value = [{...root},{...leaf1}]

watch(listCollection , (val) => {
...
 console.log(val[0].data)
//expected output: root1 data

 console.log(val[1].data)
//expected output:leaf1 data

// but it both throws: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

}}, { deep: true })
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in listCollection">
    <select-list v-model="item.data" :items="item.selectListItems">
       in here is some logic that binds the selected data from selectLstItems to the v-model on click, it works as intened
    </select-list>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### Error message in `watch` by `console.log`

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Comment: why you don't use `debugger` in the watcher to see what structure of your `val`?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev the val looks completley correct to me

`[{  data:"",   key:"",  selectListItems....}]`

Comment: Have you considered handling the scenario where [0] or [1] values do not exist?

Comment: there's something related to a promise, maybe store.getRule is async. it's hard to say without a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. please use this as a start: https://shorturl.at/enuD9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `val[0]` does not exist, accessing `undefined.data` will result in exactly the same type error.

```js
watch(listCollection, (val) => {
  console.log(val) // will always have a value

  // check if what you want to print exists
  if (val[0] && val[0].data) {
    console.log(val[0].data);
  }

  // or in another way (if val is always guaranteed to be an array, then you only need to check if the specific element exists)
  console.log(val[1]?.data);

  console.log(val[1]?.data ?? 'val[1] not object');
}, { deep: true });
```

- [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) - MDN Docs

Comment: OMG, why didn't I think of that…  That's it. Thanks!